# How to create a pom.xml file with Gradle using variables?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I want to write a Gradle function, which creates a `pom.xml` file with data (groupId, artifactId, version) passed as arguments.

I created following script:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'

def createMainPom(mainDir, groupId, artifactId, version)
{
    pom
    {
        project
        {
            groupId '$groupId' // Error
            artifactId '$artifactId'
            version '$version'
            packaging 'pom'
            name 'New app'
            modules
            {
                module
                {
                    name 'app'
                }
                module
                {
                    name 'integration-tests'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo('$mainDir/pom.xml');
}
[...]
```

When I run it, I get the error at the position marked with `// Error` above:

```
> No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument typ
es: (java.lang.String) values: [a]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), split(java.lang.String), find(jav
a.lang.String), count(java.lang.String)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [plugin documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) states:

> Note: `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, and `packaging` should always be set directly on the `pom` object.

Does moving those properties up a level, out of `project`, make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

For strings variables resolution use double quotes:

```
groupId "$groupId"
artifactId "$artifactId"
version "$version"

...

}.writeTo("$mainDir/pom.xml");
```